# Bash - move all files from subdirectories to up folders

Tags: bash, move

```
/volume1/TVPack/A/Folder1/Folder11/ --> files
/volume1/TVPack/A/Folder2/Folder22/ --> files
/volume1/TVPack/B/Folder3/Folder33/ --> files
(the list goes on)...
```

I want to move all files from **Folder11/22** to /volume1/TVPack/**A**
and all files from **Folder33** to /volume1/TVPack/**B**
**etc**
ie, move 2 levels up

The code that I'm using is

```
find /volume1/TVPack/*/ -type f -mindepth 3 -exec mv -- {} /volume1/TVPack/*/ \;
```

But this put all the files only in folder B, instead of putting the respective files to A and the respectives files to B.

I'm doing this on a task scheduler, so I think that I can't use `mv * .[^.]*`

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-execdir`, which cd's to the directory each file is in before executing the command.

```
find /volume1/TVPack/*/ -type f -mindepth 3 -execdir mv -- {} ../../ \;
```

Even better, use `+` instead of `\;` to minimize the number of `mv` commands.

```
find /volume1/TVPack/*/ -type f -mindepth 3 -execdir mv -t ../../ -- {} +
```